# Nodejs + SocketIO + MySql Connections Not Closing Properly and Creating Database Overhead

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I've been having this issue for over a couple of months now, and still can't seem to figure out how to fix it.  It seems that I'm experiencing a high number of connections to our database, and I assume it's because our connections aren't closing properly which is causing them to hang for long periods of time.  In return this causes a lot of overhead which occasionally causes our web application to crash.  Currently the application runs the `promise-mysql` npm package to create a connection and query the database.  Our web application uses `socketio` to request these connections to our `mysql` database.

I'm working with existing code that was here before me, so I did not set it up this way.  This makes it a bit more confusing for me to debug this issue because I'm not that familiar with how the connections get closed after a successful / unsuccessful query.

When logging errors from our server I'm getting messages like this:

```
db error { Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/ec2-user/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:113:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19) fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

(Not sure if that has anything to do with the high number of connections I'm seeing or not)

I recently changed the `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` to `5000` in `MySql`, which is way lower than the default `28800`, but setting it to this stopped the application from crashing so often.

This is the code for creating the database connection:

database.js file

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';
import env from '../../../env.config.json';

const db = async (sql, descriptor, serializedParameters = []) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            //const connection = mysql.createPool({
                host: env.DB.HOST,
                user: env.DB.USER,
                password: env.DB.PASSWORD,
                database: env.DB.NAME,
                port: env.DB.PORT
            })
            if (connection && env.ENV === "development") {
                //console.log(/*"There is a connection to the db for: ", descriptor*/);
            }
                let result; 

                if(serializedParameters.length > 0) {
                    result = await connection.query(sql, serializedParameters)
                } else result = await connection.query(sql);
                connection.end();
                resolve(result);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR pool.db: " + e);
            reject(e);
        };         
    });
}

export default db;
```

And this is an example of what the sockets look like:

sockets.js file

```
socket.on('updateTimeEntry', async (time, notes, TimeEntryID, callback) => {
        try {
            const results = await updateTimeEntry(time, notes, TimeEntryID);
            callback(true);
            //socket.emit("refreshJobPage", false, "");
        }
        catch (error) {
            callback(false);
        }
    });

    socket.on('selectDatesFromTimeEntry', (afterDate, beforeDate, callback) => {
        const results = selectDatesFromTimeEntry(afterDate, beforeDate).then((results) => {
            //console.log('selectLastTimeEntry: ', results);
            callback(results);
        })
    });
```

And this is an example of the methods that get called from the sockets to make a connection to the database

timeEntry.js file

```
import db from './database';

export const updateTimeEntry = (time, notes, TimeEntryID) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const updateTimeEntry = `UPDATE mytable SET PunchOut = NOW(), WorkTimeTotal = '${time}', Notes = "${notes}" WHERE TimeEntryID = '${TimeEntryID}';`

            const response = await db(updateTimeEntry, "updateTimeEntry");
            resolve(response[0]);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR TimeEntry.updateTimeEntry: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};

//Gets a List for Assigned Jobs 
export const selectDatesFromTimeEntry = (afterDate, beforeDate) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const selectDatesFromTimeEntry = `SELECT * FROM mytable.TimeEntry WHERE PunchIn >= '${afterDate}' && PunchIn < '${beforeDate}';`
            //console.log("Call: " + selectDatesFromTimeEntry);
            const response = await db(selectDatesFromTimeEntry, "selectDatesFromTimeEntry");
            //console.log("Response: " + response);
            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR TimeEntry.selectDatesFromTimeEntry: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

I just really want to figure out why I'm noticing so much overhead with my database connections, and what I can do to resolve it.  I really don't want to have to keep restarting my server each time it crashes, so hopefully I can find some answers to this.  If anyone has any suggestions or knows what I can change in my code to solve this issue that would help me out a lot, thanks!

**EDIT 1**

These are the errors I'm getting from `mysql`

```
2020-04-30T11:12:40.214381Z 766844 [Note] Aborted connection 766844 to db: 'mydb' user: 'xxx' host: 'XXXXXX' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2020-04-30T11:12:48.155598Z 766845 [Note] Aborted connection 766845 to db: 'mydb' user: 'xxx' host: 'XXXXXX' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2020-04-30T11:15:53.167160Z 766848 [Note] Aborted connection 766848 to db: 'mydb' user: 'xxx' host: 'XXXXXX' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

**EDIT 2**

Is there a way I can see why some of these connections would be hanging or going idle?

**EDIT 3**

I've been looking into using a `pool` instead, as it seems that it is a more scalable and appropriate solution for my application.  How can I achieve this with the existing code that I have?

Comment: first check of the server  has any messages why he closed

Comment: @nbk the one that I posted is the only one that I've seen come through so far from the server.  It says it closed the connection, but there isn't much to go off of after that.

Comment: It would be in the mysql logs, not the nodejs logs.

Comment: you have done what you could on client site, but i meant that you should look at the error log of the mysql server too check if there are erros

Comment: @nbk We use an RDS instance from AWS for this, I will check there and edit my post with those logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening a new connection for each and every query... Opening a connection is slow, there is a lot of overhead for doing so, and your server certainly does not have unlimited number of connections allowed. The NodeJS mysql package provides a pooling mechanism which would be a lot more efficient for you.

The goal is to reuse the connections as much as possible instead of always disposing of them right after the first query.

In your db.js, create a pool on startup and use it:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10, //Number of connections to create.
  host: env.DB.HOST,
  user: env.DB.USER,
  password: env.DB.PASSWORD,
  database: env.DB.NAME,
  port: env.DB.PORT
});
```

To execute your query, you would simply do this:

```
await pool;
return pool.query(sql, serializedParameters);
```

Comment: Could you show how that would be implemented within the code I have provided?  Sorry, I'm new to this package and don't know exactly how it works.  Also I think we have maximum connections set to 40 or something.  Do you think this will fix the high number of connections that I'm seeing?

Comment: @salketer What minimum version of MySQL is required?  Any MySQL Global Variable requirements, such as thread_pool_size, thread_handling, or any others for the functionality?

Comment: When you say ```on startup```, are you referring to when the application itself starts up, or are you talking about when I'm making a query request?  Sorry, just some of this seems a little vague to me.